# Structural breaks in Survival Analysis

Tags: survival, cox-model, kaplan-meier, change-point, chow-test

I am currently conducting research using panel data to analyze survival patterns. This involves examining the time-to-event data of a diverse group of participants over multiple years, where the durations are typically very short (measured in seconds or minutes). Given the longitudinal nature of the data, I anticipate the presence of structural breaks or regime changes (over the years, so not *within* the event period itself). I suspect that the time-to-event (which is typically a few seconds or minutes) will change over the years.

Essentially, the participants enter the study at different times. This can be a difference of years. When using survival analysis models, it is usually assumed that this does not matter. I want to be able to identify structural breaks based on the time when participants enter the study.

One potential approach would be to divide my sample period into multiple time periods, such as few years, and analyze each period separately. This allows me to examine changes in survival patterns across different time intervals and compare them. However, choosing the time periods myself would be rather subjective. I am looking for a statistical test or model that can identify the time periods by using only the data.

I am interested in exploring statistical tests that can help identify these structural breaks in the data. Could you provide any guidance or literature references that specifically address the identification of structural breaks in survival analysis models with panel data?

Comment: Is the event death?  If not what is the event you are analyzing, and is it the kind of setup where a longitudinal current status approach might fit better?

Comment: @FrankHarrell The event is a trade occuring. This is typically several seconds or minutes after the start time (which is defined as the moment someone requests to sell or buy a product). I have several years of intraday data with requests and trades occurring, and wish to see whether there is/are structural changes in the time to trade over the sample period.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm still not quite clear on whether this is best thought of as time-to-event or as trade=0/1 longitudinally as in a multi-state model where trade is considered an absorbing state if no further trade is possible, or as a regular state otherwise.

Comment: A trade occurring can indeed also be conceptualized as a binary outcome (0 or 1). I instead thought of it as a time-to-event variable because it potentially allows for a more nuanced examination of the duration between the request and the trade. Specifically it allows for investigation of factors that may influence the duration of trades, as well as the influence of factors on a transaction *not* taking place (because this can also happen: someone asking to buy/sell, but a transaction does not take place). However, I am unsure how to identify structural breaks or regimes with this setup.

Comment: @FrankHarrell With the data I could essentially construct (daily) survival curves based on all the intra-day data that is available every day. So then I would have a different survival curve for each day of my sample period (which spans several years). Would it not be possible to identify structural changes in these survival curves over time?

Comment: It sounds slightly more appropriate to model instantaneous (daily) trade risk and one of several predictive covariates might be a smooth nonlinear function of calendar time or time since some index event (using e.g. a regression spline).

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thanks a lot for thinking along with me. How could I use this setup to identify potential structural breaks in the data?

Comment: See the case study [here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/genreg.html#sec-genreg-gtrans) but ignore the discontinuity part for now.  Basically you fit a flexible time trend and examine the fit and its confidence bands closely.  Note that the case study ignores correlation structure.  Question: do you track for repeated trades or is the initial trade an absorbing event?

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thanks. The same product can indeed be traded multiple times, so there is definitely some correlation structure that I need to account for.

Comment: A Markov process is probably appropriate then, where the current trade tendency (probability) depends on the trade history.  If an adequate summary of the history is to use the most recent trade status then it's a first-order Markov process.  If the current trade risk depends on the proportion of previous time periods for which a trade was made then the correlation structure is in line with a random intercepts mixed effects model.